# indexOf method in lists always return -1

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List <Model> list = [Model('samsung'), Model('apple')]
print(list.indexOf(Model('apple'))) // always -1
```

How can i retrieve the right index of list

Comment: You are checking index of a new instance, that is not in the list.
try to create an instance outside and add it ... something like this:
final apple = Model('apple');
List <Model> list = [Model('samsung'), apple],
print(list.indexOf(apple)) 
should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexOf.html) of the `indexOf` method:

> The first time an object o is encountered so that o == element, the index of o is returned.
>
> [...]
>   Returns -1 if element is not found.

So, it looks for each element of the list and compare with the one you provided using the equality operator.
Since you are looking for a complex type "Model" you should override the equality operator to make it compare the attributes you want. Without doing so, the default behavior is that two objects are only equal if they are the exact same object, as stated [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#equality):

> [...] two objects generally only have the same hash code if they are the exact same object.

In order to override the equality operator, you can do it by yourself using the native dart capabilities, like this:

```
class Model {
  final String name;

  const Model(this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Model &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

or with a package to make it easier, like this famous ["equatable"](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable):

```
class Model extends Equatable {
  final String name;

  Person(this.name);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
}
```