# Flutter list.indexOf(element) always returns -1

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i'm trying to get indexes of elements in a list using Flutter and Getx. The problem is that it is always returning `-1` whatever element I pass into `indexOf()`.

Here is my code:

```
var my_index = Get.find<ProductsController>()
                                  .productsList
                                  .indexOf(_cartList[index].product!);

print(my_index); ==> always retuning -1
```

Noting that _cartList and productsList have elements inside of them. Even when I pass an element manually it always returns `-1`.

Comment: What does your list elements consist of?  Does it support a proper == and hashCode for comparisons?

Comment: minus one is returned in that case if the value is not present in the list check your list if whether it contains data or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660975/2252830

Comment: Actually my list consists of Instances of ProductModel, and I'm trying to fetch the index of each one of them! I figured out that productsList has json objects in it, while _cartList has Instances of ProductModel, so I should probably convert them from json in order to do the comparison! is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually -1 is the standard message to tell that the element not exist in the list searched.

Maybe it is but the comparison can't be made (==) ? Are the types rigorously accurate? Do you use equatable or an equivalent (freezed, ...). If you are able to do it with a list of integer or string it is probably from there

Comment: roductsList has json objects in it, while _cartList has Instances of ProductModel, so I should probably convert them from json in order to do the comparison! is that it?

Comment: Or use equatable if the product don't need to be "exactly" the same. https://pub.dev/packages/equatable